# All Pass Filter

Tags: filter

Consider the next transfer function:

$$H(z) = \frac{b+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}$$

where \$a\$ is a real number and \$|a| < 1\$.

My intention is to make an all pass filter, for that I need to determine for what value or values of \$b\$, such that the frequency response \$He^{iω}\$ satisfies the condition \$| H (e^{iω}) | = 1\$.

Comment: What makes this the "next" transfer function, is it part of a homework assignment or exam? Do you have a specific question? What have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: `My intention is to make an all pass filter` Fine but I believe you're asking for some type of mathematical answer, which would be considered off-topic here. It would only be on-topic here if you're asking about the behavior of such filter given this equation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson If think OP means * Consider the **following** transfer function:*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is homework, so a few hints:

- write out the magnitude of H(z) using 
  $$|H(z)|=\sqrt{\text{Re}(H(z))^2+\text{Im}(H(z))^2}$$
- if you can *prove* you cannot find any combination of \$a\$ and \$b\$ for which every (dependancy of) \$z\$ is eliminated, then
  $$|H(z)|\neq 1 $$

Examples of 'proves'

- you can prove you cannot eliminate variable \$z\$ in \$H(z)=a+z\$ for any value of a
- you can prove you can eliminate variable \$z\$ in \$H(z)=az+b\$ for a combination of \$a\$ and \$b\$ (you set \$a=0\$)